# Segmentation fault after 24 iterations

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am writing this code for which has a large array `size = 10000` values

```
    BYTE** _rawDataByte;

     _rawDataByte = (BYTE**)malloc(size*sizeof(BYTE*));

    size_t counter = 0;
    for(size_t i =0; i<size; i++)
    {   
        //Assign values to device varibles

        //Calculate rawDataByte
        std::string rawData(_bytesRaw);
        
        _rawDataByte[i] = (BYTE*)hex2bytes(rawData.c_str());

        std::cout << ++counter <<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout <<"Step 00 completed" <<std::endl;
```

So, I am getting segfault at the double pointer _rawDataByte. I am using nvcc compiler on Linux.

Comment: `int* _runs = new int;` allocates a single `int`. `_runs[i] = stepSize;` is wrong for any `i != 0`. That it was running "ok" for 24 iterations is just (bad) luck

Comment: In general please post [mcve]s. This implies removing anything that's unnecessary to reproduce the issue, and including everything that's required to make the code runnable. Do *not* post code fragments.

Comment: Explicit use of `new` and `delete` is considered a bad practice since C++11! In fact in your case it is bad practice even for C++98

Comment: @MarekR the use of malloc is even worse!

Comment: use `std::vector`

Comment: I cant, I have to pass it to the cuda kernel which takes unsigned char**

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
BYTE** _rawDataByte = new BYTE*;
```

allocates one `BYTE*`.

This line:

```
_rawDataByte[i] = ... blah blah ...
```

writes the `i`'th `BYTE*` (starting from 0). If `i` isn't 0, then it's out of bounds. `_runs` has the same problem.